# Resources for learning LINQ and Entity Framework Queries?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

everyone. I'm trying to learn how to write LINQ queries, and am wondering if you can help me kick-start it with some resource recommendations.

I am trying to learn how to write simple and complex queries that look like this, which I *think* is standard LINQ syntax ...

```
from b in blahCollection
join f in fooCollection
where b.Field == someValue
select new { b.Field, f.field }
```

... and this, though I'm not sure what this syntax is called. (What **is** it called?)

```
var plan = blahCollection.Find(b => b.Field == someValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

The best resources, I think, would be those that would allow me to practice queries on sample databases. I've heard about [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), but have not yet evaluated it. Is this a good choice? Are there better choices?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx

Comment: Your first snippet is called query syntax, your second is method syntax. Read msdn. This isn't a valid question and will probably be closed. If you have a solid understanding of basic set theory the docs on msdn are more than adequate for becoming proficient in LINQ.

Comment: Not a valid question ... Okay, I can see that it probably doesn't fit in some way. But, it is an honest question. I really did need to pointer you've given, which I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN is the way to go, here's a link to the "Getting started with LINQ" for C# pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx